# How to query absenteeism in a mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, learners table has learners information, site table has site information that learner attends and attendance tabele has clock in records everyday for each user.

attendance table is joined with (id_number) to the learner table.
learner table is joined with (site_id) to site table.

I have the following tables:

`learner`

```
|---------------------|--------|--------------|-------------|
|      id_number      |site_id |   fname      |   lname     |
|---------------------|--------|--------------|-------------|
|          552        |    1   |     John     |    Doe      |
|---------------------|--------|--------------|-------------|
|          887        |    2   |    Peter     |    Doe      |
|---------------------|--------|--------------|-------------|
|          567        |    2   |     Mary     |    Doe      |
|---------------------|--------|--------------|-------------|
```

`Site`

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      site_id        |     Site_name    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |        Denver    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        Texas     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

`Attendance`

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      id_number      |       date       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         552         |    2018-06-05    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          887        |   2018-06-05     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Code:

```
SELECT fname , lname, attendance.id_number , site_name , attendance.date 
FROM attendance 
JOIN learner on attendance.id_number = learner.id_number  
JOIN site ON learner.site_id=site.siteid 
WHERE learner.id_number NOT IN (
    SELECT attendance.id_number 
    FROM attendance 
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-06-05' ) 
ORDER BY learner.site_id ASC
```

Need assistance in getting the absent records and then count them.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say. Adjust your formatting please.

Comment: What is your expected result? Joining `attendance` with `learner` will only return the learners who are in `attendance`. Then adding `WHERE learner.id_number NOT IN ...` will filter them out, so you get an empty result.

Comment: format updated.

Comment: Expected result is to only see learners not in the attendance table in the selected date range.

Comment: @Keith Do you need to know the date on which they were absent, or just the number of days that were absent in the date range?

Comment: I need both the date at which they where absent and the count within the specific date range.